# NullPointerException while marshalling DynamicEntity

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, moxy

I'm using MOXY JAXB to generate XML files based on XSD schema using DynamicEntity. While marshalling I'm getting NPE. NPE happens only if I set field which use type "СвУчСдТип". If fields with this type was not setted then marshalling is successful.

Here is minimised XSD which I use to reproduce this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:usch="http://www.unisoftware.ru/schematron-extensions" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="КнПокСтр">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="СвПрод" type="СвУчСдТип" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="СвУчСдТип">

    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="СведЮЛ">

            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="ИННЮЛ" type="ИННЮЛТип" use="required">
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="КПП" type="КППТип" use="required">
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="СведИП">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="ИННФЛ" type="ИННФЛТип" use="required">
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="ИННФЛТип">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="12"/>
        <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})[0-9]{10}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="ИННЮЛТип">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="10"/>
        <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})[0-9]{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="КППТип">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="9"/>
        <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})([0-9A-Z]{2})([0-9]{3})"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**NewClass.java**

public class NewClass {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, SAXException{
        PageBuilder pb = PageBuilder.createPage().свПрод("5040114973           / 504001001");
        DynamicJAXBContext context = pb.getJaxbContext();
        DynamicEntity build = pb.build();
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output", Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", Charset.forName("utf-8").toString());
        marshaller.marshal(build, System.out);
    }
}
```

**PageBuilder.java**

```
public class PageBuilder {
    private static DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private  DynamicEntity entity;
    private static Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("((((0[1-9]{1}|1[0-9]{1}|2[0-8]{1})\\.(0[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1}))|((29|30)\\.(01|0[3-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1}))|(31\\.(01|03|05|07|08|10|12)))\\.((19|20)[0-9]{2}))|(29\\.02\\.((19|20)(((0|2|4|6|8)(0|4|8))|((1|3|5|7|9)(2|6)))))");

    private PageBuilder(){}

    public static PageBuilder createPage() throws FileNotFoundException, JAXBException{
        PageBuilder fl = new PageBuilder()
                .file("C:\\Documents and Settings\\g.ioffe\\Мои документы\\АСУ ДК\\NO_NDS.8_1_003_01_05_05_02.xsd");
        return fl;

    }

    public DynamicJAXBContext getJaxbContext() {
        return jaxbContext;
    }


    private PageBuilder file(String uri) throws FileNotFoundException, JAXBException{
        FileInputStream xsdInputStream = new FileInputStream(uri);
        jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, null, null, null);
        this.entity = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("КнПокСтр");
        return this;
    }

    public PageBuilder свПрод(String person){
        DynamicEntity personInfo = this.parsePerson(person);
        if (personInfo != null){
            List persons;
            if (this.entity.isSet("свПрод")){
                persons = this.entity.<List>get("свПрод");
            }
            else persons = new ArrayList<>();
            persons.add(personInfo);
            this.entity.set("свПрод", persons);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public DynamicEntity build(){
        return this.entity;
    }

    private DynamicEntity parsePerson(String person){
        DynamicEntity personInfo = null;
        if (person.trim().length() == 0 || person.trim().equals("/")) return null;
        String[] split = person.split("/");
        for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
            split[i] = split[i].trim();
        }
        if (split[0].length() == 12) {
            personInfo = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("СведИП");
            personInfo.set("иннфл", split[0]);
        } else if (split[0].length() == 10){
            personInfo = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("СведЮЛ");
            String kpp;
            if(split.length == 1)
                kpp = "";
            else kpp  = split[1];
            personInfo.set("иннюл",split[0]);
            personInfo.set("кпп",kpp);
        }
        return personInfo;
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NullPointerException]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:500)
        at example.minimal.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.ValuesAccessor.getAttributeValueFromObject(ValuesAccessor.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(DatabaseMapping.java:657)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.getAttributeValue(ObjectMarshalContext.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshalStreamOrWriter(XMLMarshaller.java:1147)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:934)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:877)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:496)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: There might be some encoding mess since your xml encoding is  "windows-1251" and your jaxB encoding is set to "utf-8"

Comment: @AlexeyR. Tried. Doesn't help. Stacktrace have some changes. But still NPE.